# How to change bound variable dynamically in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, string-interpolation

I think, everyone knows, how interpolation works, and we can easily interpolate single variable (may be this interpretation is not fully correct, but you will understand what I mean when will take a look at the code). But what if we want to switch between two different variables dynamically? For example, we have two class properties:

```
public first: string = '"first" variable activated';
public second: string = '"second" variable activated';
```

And have two radio buttons, bound to `activeVariableName` class property:

```
<input type="radio" value="first" [(ngModel)]="activeVariableName">
<input type="radio" value="second" [(ngModel)]="activeVariableName">
```

We can interpolate like this:

```
<h1>{{activeVariableName}}</h1>
```

But this way, we will see just **first** or **second**, which are class properties names.

So my question is: **"How to display values of this properties, but not just names?"**

Here is a [**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-benwxp?file=app%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.html)

Comment: its a valid question in all honesty, its a simple mistake that quite a lot of people would make

Comment: If somebody think so and this question will help someone - not a problem, let's keep it open

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed off the binding brackets `[]`, so the values are `first` and `second`. try:

```
<input type="radio" [value]="first" [(ngModel)]="activeVariableName">
<input type="radio" [value]="second" [(ngModel)]="activeVariableName">
```

Comment: Very simple and clear, thanks a lot! I'll accept your answer after timeout.